# Angular 6 - Select inside an ngFor

Tags: angular, forms, select, angular6, dropdown

I have a select dropdown inside a `ngFor`. How do I retrieve the value of each select inside the loop?

Also, I want to change the color of each sentence inside the `<p>` tag depending on each select's value. How would I do that?

[image]

Each sentence should have a color depending on the value selected in the dropdown next to it. And the change needs to be immediate.

The code here does not work.

```
<div *ngIf="sentences?.length > 0;else noItems">
  <ul *ngFor="let sentence of sentences;let i = index;" class="collection">
  <li class="collection-item">
     <p>{{sentence.data}} </p>
     <p style="margin-left:20px; font-size:12px!important"> 
        <select  (change)="filterChanged(selected[i])">
        <option *ngFor="let cat of foods" [value]="cat.value">
        {{cat.viewValue}}
        </option>
        </select>
     </p>
  </li>
```

## ts file:

```
filterChanged(selectedValue:string ){
    this.printedOption = selectedValue;
    console.log("COLOR",this.printedOption );
    if(this.printedOption=='1'){
        this.color="pink";
    }
    if(this.printedOption=='2'){
        this.color="red";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to check for `cat.value == x` then `<p> color = red`?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes, for just that line. Not the other lines which come under the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`[ngClass]`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) with the multiple conditions to apply a CSS class

HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <ul *ngFor="let sentence of sentences;let i = index;" class="collection">
        <li class="collection-item">
            <p [ngClass]="{'red': sentence?.disco == 1 , 'green': sentence?.disco == 2 }">{{sentence.viewValue}} </p>
            <p style="margin-left:20px; font-size:12px!important">
                <select #val (change)="onChange(val.value,i)">
            <option *ngFor="let cat of foods" [value]="cat.value" >
            {{cat.viewValue}}
            </option>
            </select>
         </p>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
}
```

TS Code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic select
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: any[] = [
    { value: '1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
    { value: '2', viewValue: 'Tacos' }
  ];

  sentences: any[] = [
    { value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak' },
    { value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
    { value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos' }
  ];

  onChange(selectedValue, index) {
    console.log(selectedValue)
    this.sentences[index].disco = selectedValue;
  }
}
```

[`Stackblitz Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwaebv)

Comment: My sentences don't have any value. It's just an array of strings. So how would I work around that?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<select #select (change)="filterChanged(select.value, sentence.data)">
```

and for change colour of <kbd>P</kbd> tag, you must define a global object, and set a key for an object in filterChanged() function:

```
public colorObj = {};

filterChanged(selectedValue:string, key) {
    let colors = {1: 'red', 2: 'green'};
    this.colorObj[key] = colors[selectedValue];
}
```

and use [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) in HTML for setting color:

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'color': colorObj[sentence.data]}">
```

Comment: This makes sense. But the sentence data doesn't appear and dropdown doesn't work (collapse down). The error shows up on the p tag line as : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Chronology of events with factual details that led to the present case between parties named therein before the court on which the judgment is delivered.' of undefined